# ClickOnce: The required version of the .NET Framework is not installed on this computer

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, clickonce, vsto

I have been getting the error "The required version of the .NET Framework is not installed on this computer." (Event Id 4096 in Event log) when trying to install a VSTO application from both a ClickOnce deployment and a local copy. This is interesting as the .NET framework is installed (on my 32bit Windows 7 PC) and the VSTO application was developed on the self same machine (and works in Visual Studio 2008).

Does anybody has an idea why I could get this exception?

> Name:  From:
>   http://localhost/BlaBla.vsto
>
> "The required version of the .NET
>   Framework is not installed on this
>   computer."
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.InstallAddInFailedException:
>   "The required version of the .NET
>   Framework is not installed on this
>   computer."    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.SolutionInstaller.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__0()

Comment: Yes I did. I have selected as prerequisites Windows Installer 3.1, .NET Framework 3.5SP1, Microsoft Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies, and Visual Studio Tools for the Office System 3.0 Runtime Service Pack 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking of the obvious causes (see comments) it seems to leave Windows 7 as the cause. Despite lots of people 'switching' to Win7 it's still a beta.

A few points come to mind:

- can you check the clickonce install on XP or Vista?
- do you have AutoUpdates turned on?

Comment: I'm having a very similar error on an XP VM. The latest .NET framework is installed as well as the VSTO runtime... I'm not sure what's causing it.

Answer (score 2):

Hey all, I was updating one of my own plugins and ran into this as well, so I thought I'd ask some friends internally :-).  Here's the skinny...

The following file is missing in Win7RC .NET distribution (this is known and being addressed):
%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\RedistList\FrameworkList.xml

Copy that file from a non Win7 machine (same location) to the Win7 box and your publish should work.

I'm traveling and haven't verified yet (don't have a non Win7 box near me), but wanted to post this for you all.

Hope this helps!

-th

Answer (score 0):

May be a mute inquiry or suggestion, but ClickOnce came out in .Net 2.0, do you have that installed?

Comment: I am running VS.NET 2008, so it is all installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definately to do with deploying from windows 7, I am dual booted windows 7 and server 2008, if I deploy the project from server 2008 its fine, but if I deploy from windows 7, it doesn't work.. 
You cannot install a VSTO clickonce application on any OS that has been deployed from windows 7.. Bugger.

This bug is known by Microsoft and it is marked as fixed, what I havent been able to find out is if its a bug in VSTO that is triggered by windows 7, or if the bug is in windows 7 itself.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a hotfix, I am still struggling with this problem, when I asked someone from microsoft about this error he looked up the bug database and found the bug, and it was marked as fixed, there was no workaround or version information about the problem or the fix. Useful aye...

We will have to wait till RC1 is released and see if it is fixed then.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 7 RC1 and have the problem.
I checked out timheur's solution but it does not fix it for me. That file exists in Windows 7 RC1

It used to work OK for me from Windows 7 Beta - (many times)
It stopped working after I visited TechEd 2009 in LA!!
But I upgraded from BETA to RC1 to about the same time.

I have just done a clean build of my PC with Windows 7 RC1 and still have the problem. 
I can publish an OK version from a Vista PC.

It seems that my version of the problem is caused by upgrading from Windows 7 Beta to Windows 7 RC1.

By the way, when I publish from a Vista PC after having published from from a Windows 7 PC the publish process advises me that the publish is being done from a different application platform. This confirms to me that the publishing platform is the cause of the problem!

And another thing... Since Windows 7 cannot properly publish a VSTO application, I decided to implement a Windows XP virtual PC on my Windows 7 machine and do it from there.
Turns out that does not work either! The resultant Outlook implementation does not recognise my Custom Task Form regions.

I hate VISTA but it seems that where I have to go. I would go back to Windows 7 BETA but Microsoft are scheduled to kill it at the end of this month.

I have now tried a couple of other things...

1. Tried to install Windows 2008 Server as VM on Windows 7 RC! Could not get it to install!
2. Tried to install Virtual Server 2007 on Windows 7 RC1. That did not work and it killed the Windows 7 Virtual Server.
3. Tried replacing the FrameworkList.xml with the version from Vista. That did not help.

Can anyone tell me if this problem has any priority within Microsoft? It is a deal breaker for Windows 7 and the RTM is not far away!!